# PIC32MX cannot change select TRIS bits

Tags: microcontroller, pic, microchip

hopefully I have the right forum here.

Firstly:

**Processor:** PIC32MX795F512L (on the chipKIT mx32 dev board)

**IDE:** MPLAB X IDE v2.26

**Pogrammer/Debugger:** PicKIT 3

I am trying to set some of the PORT pins to outputs so I can bit bang a communication protocol to another device. However, when I run the PIC using the pickit 3 as a debugger, I find that some of the TRIS bits won't toggle to 0.

This is an issue I am having with just TRISF and TRISG so far, and I have seen some mention of it in other posts, but no solution.

The pins I have tried to toggle are:

- TRISF4 (SDA3A/SDI3A/U3ARX/PMA9/CN17/RF4)
- TRISG3 (D-/RG3)
- TRISG2 (D+/RG2)

here is an example of how I am doing it.

```
ODCDCLR = 0xFFFF;
ODCFCLR = 0xFFFF;
TRISDCLR = 3<<14;
TRISFCLR = 3<<5;
```

What could be some causes for a sticky TRIS bit?

Comment: There are many possible issues so more information might be useful in pinning down the exact cause. For example, which pins work and which pins don't work? What are your configuration bits set to? Do you load zeros into the LATx or PORTx registers? Ideally you could post a minimal example of your code (with extras removed) to help answer these questions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you look at [page 36 of the datasheet](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/61156G.pdf), you will see that G2 and G3 are input-only when used as digital I/O instead of USB. Excerpt below:

[image: pins]

Similarly, if you have UART3 enabled, RF4 will be an RX input.

You need to make sure you enable/disable the peripherals sharing those pins and read the datasheet *very* carefully. It's a complete PITA sometimes, but I've never found the datasheet to be wrong - just sometimes things are well hidden!

Comment: Eventually the datasheet will be right. The initial dspic[24/33]e sheets were a trainwreck

Answer (score 0):

Two big causes are a pin configured for analog and a pin configured for some other function, like JTAG.

For F and G, you would set `ANSELF = 0` and `ANSELG = 0`. For JTAG you'd need to check your data sheet and then set the appropriate configuration bit.

I haven't checked the data sheet for your specific device so I can't be more definitive.

Update:

See Roger Rowland's answer. No substitute for reading the data sheet!

Comment: ANSELx Register affect inputs. I have yet to see a PIC who's outputs are affected by the ANSELx.

Comment: @MathieuL. From 12.1.2 of the PIC32MZ data sheet: "If the TRIS bit is cleared (output) while the ANSELx bit is set, the digital output level (Voh or Vol) is converted by an analog peripheral, such as the ADC module or Comparator module." and "In order to use port pins for I/O functionality with digital modules, such as Timers, UARTs, etc., the corresponding ANSELx bit must be cleared."

Comment: @MathieuL. I've just been clearing the appropriate ANSELx bit based on this documentation. I have not actually tested what happens if you don't.

Comment: I can admit defeat. If the spec. sheet says so, it is likely to be true.